# "x is not a constructor" error, but invoked normally in other files

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I'm working on an Express.js with Mongoose project, with many models and controllers.  I have a common "utils" class, called `UtilsController` with many helper functions which I invoke from all the other files.  My issue is that I get a following error,

> TypeError: Utils is not a constructor

when trying to create an object of it in a file, but it perfectly works in other files, required the exact same way.

Here's examples of it:

*utils.controller.js*: **The utils class I want to import**

```
const Esplai = require('./models/espais/esplai.model.js');
// some more imports...

const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, timestamp, printf } = format;

class UtilsController {

  constructor() {
    this.something = "a";
    // ...
  }

  cursActual() {
    var avui = new Date();
    if(avui.getMonth() < 9){
      return avui.getFullYear() - 1;
    } else {
      return avui.getFullYear();
    }
  }
   // ...
}

module.exports = UtilsController
```

*criteri.model.js*: **A mongoose model where the import and instance works**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var _ = require('lodash');
const moment = require('moment');

var EdT = require('../espais/edt.model');
var Utils = require('../../utils.controller'); //The import
var ut = new Utils(); // The instance


var CrtieriSchema = new Schema({
// ...
})

// And some class methods...

module.exports = mongoose.model('criteris', CriteriSchema);
```

*equip.model.js*: **The Mongoose model file where it doesn't work**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const Utils = require('../../utils.controller.js'); // The import
const ut = new Utils(); // The instance
const _ = require('lodash');

var EquipSchema = new Schema({
// ...
})
EquipSchema.index({ 'nom': 'text'});
module.exports = mongoose.model('equips', EquipSchema);
```

As you see, the requirement and instantiation is done exactly the same and the problem is definetely not the path of the require (because it actually imports de file with the class).

And here's the error:

> TypeError: Utils is not a constructor
>       at Object. (/home/marc/prova/nen/ngx-admin/server/models/espais/equip.model.js:5:12)

Comment: It seems that you are missing a `module.exports` in the utils.controller.js file. Or you have just avoided to post it in the question?

Comment: @oniramarf just skipped that, sorry. Editing.

Comment: Probably you are having a circular dependency.